# How effective is it adding a logout command at the end of a test case?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I am running a test suite (test1, test2, test3) in Cypress. I noticed when I run this suite for the first time, they all pass. On the next test run, they fail. It seems that it is failing because the data from test3 has not been removed from the cypress browser when test1 begins to run.  Could this be a load issue or would adding a logout command at the end of each test case be the solution? Not sure what would be the solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`It seems that it is failing because the data from test3 has not been removed from the cypress browser`. First step is to find out where that data being stored ex: cookie, session storage or local storage? Once you found it, you can choose appropriate method to delete data. Incase you are interested in clearing all u can do something as below

```
beforeEach(() => {
 cy.window().then(win => win.sessionStorage.clear());
 cy.clearCookies();
 cy.clearLocalStorage();
 });
```

Make sure above syntax is correct from cypress.io.

Comment: Cypress deletes local storage, cookies, session automatically between tests. Doing it once again seems unnecessary. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Is-resetting-the-state-necessary

Comment: @pavelsaman last I checked https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/413 is still open!

Comment: then their documentaton is not in sync since they explicitly mention that Cypress clears "localStorage, cookies, sessions, etc." before each test: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Is-resetting-the-state-necessary

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a step to clear the cookies?

```
Cypress.Commands.add('logout', () => {
    cy.clearCookies().then(() => {
        cy.getCookies().should('be.empty').visit('/')
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `support/index.js` or `support/index.ts` file, you could have a call to `before(() => {}` that loads your browser up once, and then have all of your tests run in one browser session. When you run the tests again, the first thing it will do is reload the page in the browser so that you have a clean session to start from.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 solutions:

I. Add an assertion for the logout command - usualy adding an assertion solves this problem.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("shopFE_logout", (domain) => {
    cy.log('shopFE_logout - start')
    
    cy.get('[data-qa="logoutButton"]')
        .click({ force: true })
        .should('not.exist')
    cy.log('shopFE_logout - end')
})
```

II. The more secure, but not popular way - separate the test cases to be 1 per file and organize them in folders

Answer (score 0):

I found this on cypress docs "Remember, Cypress already automatically clears localStorage, cookies, sessions, etc before each test. Make sure you are not trying to clean up state that is already cleaned up by Cypress automatically."
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Is-resetting-the-state-necessary.
I don't think adding logout before each test will be a good idea.
In my test, I do login before each test and I have not done logout and still working fine

```
 describe('This is my test suite', () => {
            let credential = "";
            beforeEach(function () {
                cy.visit(Cypress.env('devUrl'));
                cy.fixture('data/common/loginData.json').then(loginData => {
                credential = loginData;
            });
         })
        
            it('This is my first testcase', () => {
                cy.myLoginCommand(credential.valid.username, credential.valid.password)
                objLocation.navToLocationPage()
                objLocation.verifySuccessMsg('Successfully Saved')
            })
        
            it('This is my second testcase', () => {
                cy.myLoginCommand(credential.valid.username, credential.valid.password)
                objLocation.navToLocationPage()
                objLocation.verifySuccessMsg('Successfully Updated')
            })
    })
```